# How to add random value function in ng2-smart-table

Tags: typescript, ng2-smart-table

I have a function that creates random values but I want to know how to add this function when I create a new record in a ng2-smart-table. I'm creating users and I need to assign them a random id.

This is my random id code:

```
stringGen(len) {
    var text = "";

    var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
      text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));

    return text;
  }

  randomID = this.stringGen(8);
```

this is my html:
list-user.component.html

```
<ng2-smart-table 
[settings]="settings" 
[source]="roles">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

this is my ts:
list-user.component.ts

```
settings = {
    columns: { 
        role_id : { 
            title: 'Role ID',
        }, 
        role_desc : {
            title: 'Role Description',
            editor: {
                type: 'textarea',
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `createConfirm` event to run code when a new record is created in the `ng2-smart-table`.

Your **template** would look like this:

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="tableSettings" [source]="tableSource" (createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

And in your **component**:

```
onCreateConfirm($event: any) {
    // `$event.newData` carries information the user wants to add to the table.
}
```

You can create the record with the ID generated by your `stringGen()` function in there, add it to the table source and load the source again to get the new record in the table with the randomly generated ID.